# How to proceed for reverse image search model using deep learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

Trying to solve image-based product search.

- product data contains about 1000 individual classes.

**So far what I did ->**

1. Data Augmentation of about 20 images per class with white background.
2. Transfer learning ResNet50 and custom layers.

```
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,
input_shape = (224,224,3))
input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = model(input)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = model.add(Dropout(0.5))
x = model.add(Dense(2048,activation="relu"))
x = model.add(Dropout(0.2))
x = model.add(Dense(1024,activation="relu"))
x = Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)
model_similarity_optimized = Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
```

3. After training popped the last layer which contains class & using the further features.
4. saving features as pickle file and in the time of prediction using model for features extraction and comparing the features with saved features. Brute force doing the distance measuring part for similarity.

The result is satisfactory if I use the trained image but it's failing the validation part i.e. If I upload a product by capturing with a different background the detection rate reduces by 30%. Is there anything else that I should try or change?

Comment: This might help you: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

Comment: however you weigh the feature vectors' components may need adjusting. -- perhaps ask this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ because this needs a higher level, conceptual solution. it's very much less about programming.